# How it is possible to parse XML with unsorted elements?

Tags: java, xml, annotations, jackson, javabeans

How it is possible to parse XML with unsorted elements (see [xml structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGzP3.png)) into a following JavaBean using Jackson?

The problem is that the current implementation is only capable of parsing the first "str" and "arr" element and adds them to respective collections under DocBean. However all further occurrences of these elements are simply ignored. I bet this is due to that fact that "str" and "arr" elements are not "blocked together".

XML (result element may contain * doc elements):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">0</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="fl">id,g,a,v,p,ec,timestamp,tags</str>
            <str name="sort">score desc,timestamp desc,g asc,a asc,v desc</str>
            <str name="indent">off</str>
            <str name="q">1:"e486ad917028b52265610206fb5a1e2b5914b94b"</str>
            <str name="wt">xml</str>
            <str name="version">2.2</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
        <doc>
            <str name="a">xmlrpc-client</str>
            <arr name="ec">
                <str>-sources.jar</str>
                <str>-javadoc.jar</str>
                <str>.jar</str>
                <str>.pom</str>
            </arr>
            <str name="g">org.apache.xmlrpc</str>
            <str name="id">org.apache.xmlrpc:xmlrpc-client:3.1.3</str>
            <str name="p">jar</str>
            <arr name="tags">
                <str>handle</str>
                <str>apache</str>
                <str>remote</str>
                <str>extensions</str>
                <str>version</str>
                <str>simpler</str>
                <str>over</str>
                <str>compared</str>
                <str>implement</str>
                <str>procedure</str>
                <str>protocol</str>
                <str>vendor</str>
                <str>easier</str>
                <str>important</str>
                <str>introduces</str>
                <str>calls</str>
                <str>stable</str>
                <str>much</str>
                <str>that</str>
                <str>http</str>
                <str>implementation</str>
                <str>popular</str>
                <str>specification</str>
                <str>original</str>
                <str>several</str>
                <str>java</str>
                <str>uses</str>
                <str>soap</str>
            </arr>
            <long name="timestamp">1265472806000</long>
            <str name="v">3.1.3</str>
        </doc>
    </result>
</response>
```

JavaBeans I've tried so far:

ResponseBean:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "response")
public class MVNSearch {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "doc")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "result")
    private List<MVNSearchDoc> docs;

    public List<MVNSearchDoc> getDocs() {
        return docs;
    }

    public void setDocs(List<MVNSearchDoc> docs) {
        this.docs = docs;
    }
}
```

DocBean:

```
public class MVNSearchDoc {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "str")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<MVNSearchStr> strs;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "arr")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<MVNSearchArr> arrs;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "long")
    private MVNSearchLong timestamp;

    public List<MVNSearchStr> getStrs() {
        return strs;
    }

    public void setStrs(List<MVNSearchStr> strs) {
        this.strs = strs;
    }

    public List<MVNSearchArr> getArrs() {
        return arrs;
    }

    public void setArrs(List<MVNSearchArr> arrs) {
        this.arrs = arrs;
    }

    public MVNSearchLong getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(MVNSearchLong timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }   
}
```

StrBean / ArrBean (very similar):

```
public class MVNSearchStr {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String name;

    @JacksonXmlText
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post a sample input xml text (not picture!)

Comment: Updated the question, xml file is attached

Comment: *I bet this is due to that fact that "str" and "arr" elements are not "blocked together"* ...did you test this theory? And if so, why not sort XML prior to processing?

Comment: Yes, i've tested it. How am I able to sort elements without having any ability to parse / read them?